# "Java returned exit code=13" when starting Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jre, jdk

I have some problems starting Eclipse. When I try to start it, this error window appears:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Are you using Win 7 32 or 64 bit? What version of Eclipse is installed? What version of Java is installed?

Comment: @matrixx333 Windows 64 bit, Eclipse version 3.7.2, jdk1.7.0_02, jre7 and the newest Java.

Comment: ...and your sure both your Eclipse and JDK's are the 64 bit versions?

Comment: @matrixx333 Yes.

Comment: I know this sound stupid.. But I downloaded it again from another website and now it works :D, thanks for posting though :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs when your java version and OS version is different, if your window version is 64 bit but u installed 32 bit java version or vise versa then u will face this kind of issue, just check both version if all versions are same then check your eclipse version.

Comment: how do you check the version of java?